# Can python modules downloaded through pip(3) “phone home”, with logs of your activity?

Tags: python, pip, privacy, malware-detection

Do I understand correctly that the best way to make sure is to go through module’s code and see for myself?

Comment: Python code can do absolutely anything, it doesn't matter how you obtained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**.

When you install Python modules through PIP, you are installing any code contained within those modules. And note that Python modules allow code execution not only at run time, but [also at install time](https://github.com/mschwager/0wned). To prevent this, only install binary distribution Python wheels using the `--only-binary :all:` flag. This avoids arbitrary code execution on installation (by avoiding `setup.py`).

In addition to this, you can also help mitigate against malicious packages by:

- Installing packages with the local user using the `--user` flag.
- And installing packages in hash-checking mode using the `--require-hashes` flag.